# Error while reading access token value from Web API response

Tags: c#, rest, circuit-sdk

I am trying to read Rest Web API response. I am getting error while parsing the data

Response Content type :   application/json; charset=utf-8

Response: {"access_token":"ot-a4943ac25cf94df3adacd11c71b8ea01","token_type":"Bearer","scope":["READ_USER_PROFILE","WRITE_CONVERSATIONS","READ_CONVERSATIONS"]}

DTO:

```
public class ResponseData
    {
        public string AccessToken { get; set; }
        public string TokenType { get; set; }
        public string Scope { get; set; }
    }

public class Scope
    {
        public string[] RequestScope { get; set; }
    }
```

Code:

```
using (HttpContent rescontent = response.Result.Content)
            {
                // ... Read the string.
                Task<string> result = rescontent.ReadAsStringAsync();
               // res = result.Result;

                var responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseData>(result.Result);

                Console.WriteLine("Response: {0}", responseData.AccessToken);
            }
```

Error:
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path 'scope', line 1, position 85.'

Programming Language : C#

Please let me know, how to correct this? I want to read the access token parameter from the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the *array* denoted by `[` and `]` in the *json*

```
{ 
   "access_token":"ot-a4943ac25cf94df3adacd11c71b8ea01",
   "token_type":"Bearer",
   "scope":[ // this is an array
      "READ_USER_PROFILE",
      "WRITE_CONVERSATIONS",
      "READ_CONVERSATIONS"
   ]
}
```

You need to modify your class

```
public List<string> Scope { get; set; }
```

or

```
public string[] Scope { get; set; }
```

**Edit**

You may also have other errors, so you might need to change to this

```
public string Access_Token { get; set; }
public string Token_Type { get; set; }
```

or

```
[JsonProperty("access_token")]
public string Access_Token { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("token_type")]
public string TokenType { get; set; }
```